# Black screen on boot after installing ati drivers

Tags: drivers, ati, xubuntu

System: Xubuntu 12.10 x86

I installed the Ati drivers using the Software Center, everything apparently whent fine (no error messages).

After rebooting the system i get a black screen. The system responds to input (if i press the power down button it closes gracefully) but is completely unusable.
From the boot menu i can decide to load the root terminal, but i have no idea of what to do in order to remove the drivers.

Following some guides i looked for:

- the Xorg.conf file in /etc/X11
- /usr/share/fglrx/fglrx-uninstall.sh
- /usr/share/ati/fglrx-uninstall.sh

But they were all missing.
What steps can i take?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known problem with ATI drivers on Ubuntu 12.10 (see https://bugs.launchpad.net/fglrx/+bug/1068661/+index?comments=all). I got my hybrid graphics system working by following the instructions below:

[How do I get AMD/Intel Hybrid Graphics drivers to work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205112/ubuntu-12-10-amd-intel-hybrid-graphics-not-working)

If you don't want to compile drivers, installing the `xserver-xorg-video-intel` and one of the `fglrx` packages from this PPA should work:

https://launchpad.net/~andrikos/+archive/ppa/+packages?field.name_filter=&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=quantal

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution: i had to enable networking and then use:

`sudo apt-get remove fglrx*`

This seemed to fix things up.