# Ubuntu 12.10 ATI Driver 12.11 fails after compiz and xorg update

Tags: 12.10, ati, compiz

I updated my system via the package manager from Unity and next restart was just blackness. After being here: http://linux.hootip.com/amd-catalyst-12-11-beta-fix-and-installation-the-drivers-on-ubuntu-12-11/ I had the Catalyst 12.11 Beta driver installed. I checked my /var/log/apt/history.log and the update I received was of compiz and xorg packages. I tried to get latest release info, but all I get from their pages are commit info; I can't tell what was n the package update I got served. Anyone knows what was in the latest xorg/compiz release that broke the driver? Which driver should I use now?

For completeness this is how I got the system back to boot (probably lame and not elegant):

1. Boot with GRUB selection "More Ubuntu options (or sth like that),
2. From secondary screen select 3.5.0-19 with boot options,
3. When system prompts on stuff you'd like to do, select "root" - Drop to root shell,
4. There:

   ```
   # mount -o remount,rw /
   # mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.failed
   # /usr/share/ati/fglrx-uninstall.sh 
   # reboot
   ```

This got be back on my feet.

Comment: You should edit this question and put the answer as an answer to the question.  There is nothing wrong with answering your own question, especially if it has been researched and works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening to lots of people.  Installation instructions can be found in my reply here: [Black screen on boot after installing ati drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/226507/black-screen-on-boot-after-installing-ati-drivers/226531#226531)