# Ubuntu 12.10 OpenCL OpenGL Interop with ATI graphics

Tags: drivers, ati, xorg, opengl, opencl

I have successfully installed the ATI Catalyst drivers on a my ATI hybrid graphics system running on Ubuntu 12.10.  I have verified that OpenCL and OpenGL work independently; however OpenCL-OpenGL interop is not functioning correctly.  I've done some debugging, but am not sure where to go from here.  Can anyone help?

Details:

My system is an HP Envy 6 running Ubuntu 12.10 (all updates applied) with a ATI hybrid graphics system composed of an Radeon 7600m and Intel HD3000.  I installed the latest ATI Beta drivers (v. 12.11) following these instructions:

[How do I get AMD/Intel Hybrid Graphics drivers to work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205112/ubuntu-12-10-amd-intel-hybrid-graphics-not-working)

Doing this I was able to get OpenGL and OpenCL operational.  `glxgears` runs at ~1200 fps and all of the OpenCL-only samples in the AMD APP SDK function as expected.  However, any OpenCL-OpenGL interop applications fail to launch with a `X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)` error. All of the sample code previously worked under Ubuntu 12.04 with the package manager ATI drivers.

To get a little more debugging information, I ran `LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose /opt/AMDAPP/samples/opencl/bin/x86_64/SimpleGL`. This detects my discrete GPU, appears to select the right drivers, and detects that OpenCL-OpenGL interop is enabled:

```
$ LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose ./SimpleGL
ukiDynamicMajor: found major device number 250
ukiDynamicMajor: found major device number 250
ukiDynamicMajor: found major device number 250
ukiOpenDevice: node name is /dev/ati/card0
ukiOpenDevice: open result is 7, (OK)
ukiGetBusid returned 'PCI:1:0:0'
ukiOpenDevice: node name is /dev/ati/card1
ukiOpenDevice: UKI_ERR_NOT_ROOT
...
ukiOpenDevice: node name is /dev/ati/card15
ukiOpenDevice: UKI_ERR_NOT_ROOT
ukiDynamicMajor: found major device number 250
ukiOpenByBusid: Searching for BusID PCI:1:0:0
ukiOpenDevice: node name is /dev/ati/card0
ukiOpenDevice: open result is 7, (OK)
ukiOpenByBusid: ukiOpenMinor returns 7
ukiOpenByBusid: ukiGetBusid reports PCI:1:0:0
ukiDynamicMajor: found major device number 250
ukiDynamicMajor: found major device number 250
ukiOpenByBusid: Searching for BusID PCI:1:0:0
ukiOpenDevice: node name is /dev/ati/card0
ukiOpenDevice: open result is 7, (OK)
ukiOpenByBusid: ukiOpenMinor returns 7
ukiOpenByBusid: ukiGetBusid reports PCI:1:0:0
Platform 0 : Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
Platform found : Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.

Selected Platform Vendor : Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
Device 0 : Turks Device ID is 0x1a16b40
Number of displays 1
libGL: AtiGetClientDriverName: 9.1.11 fglrx (screen 0)
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/fglrx/dri/fglrx_dri.so
ukiDynamicMajor: found major device number 250
ukiDynamicMajor: found major device number 250
ukiOpenByBusid: Searching for BusID PCI:1:0:0
ukiOpenDevice: node name is /dev/ati/card0
ukiOpenDevice: open result is 10, (OK)
ukiOpenByBusid: ukiOpenMinor returns 10
ukiOpenByBusid: ukiGetBusid reports PCI:1:0:0
glXCreateContextAttribsARB 0x7f4e05938280
Number of interoperable devices 1
Interop Device ID is 0x1a16b40
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/fglrx/dri/tls/i965_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/fglrx/dri/i965_dri.so
libGL error: dlopen /usr/lib/fglrx/dri/i965_dri.so failed     (/usr/lib/fglrx/dri/i965_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or     directory)
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib32/fglrx/dri/tls/i965_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib32/fglrx/dri/i965_dri.so
libGL error: dlopen /usr/lib32/fglrx/dri/i965_dri.so failed     (/usr/lib32/fglrx/dri/i965_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/fglrx/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib/fglrx/dri/swrast_dri.so
libGL error: dlopen /usr/lib/fglrx/dri/swrast_dri.so failed (/usr/lib/fglrx/dri/swrast_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib32/fglrx/dri/tls/swrast_dri.so
libGL: OpenDriver: trying /usr/lib32/fglrx/dri/swrast_dri.so
libGL error: dlopen /usr/lib32/fglrx/dri/swrast_dri.so failed (/usr/lib32/fglrx/dri/swrast_dri.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  155 (GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  5 (X_GLXMakeCurrent)
  Serial number of failed request:  28
  Current serial number in output stream:  28
```

I'm not sure where to go from here. This could either be a lingering issue with the known ATI Ubuntu 12.10 problems or something new.  Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok.  Figured it out (at least in my case).  The `libGL.so` file in `/usr/lib/fglrx` is not found by by the linker. Adding

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/usr/lib/fglrx
```

to my `~/.bashrc` (or `~/.profile`) made it work.  This shouldn't be required though because the driver installer adds `/usr/lib/fglrx` to the `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/x86_64-linux-gnu_GL.conf` file.

EDIT Note:
My previous post blamed this bug on Cinnamon ([bug 1483](https://github.com/linuxmint/Cinnamon/issues/1483)); however, this was incorrect. The solution documented is correct.