# Dell Inspiron 15R [Special Edition] fan speed problem

Tags: drivers, hardware, dell, temperature

I have a Dell Inspiron 15R SE ([click here](http://www.dell.com/us/p/inspiron-15r-se-7520/pd) for details). I have installed Ubuntu 12.10 via Wubi on it. The OS works perfectly fine, but there are some issues:

- The fan speed is so high that it is actually audible. This doesn't happens when working with Windows 7.
- The laptop gets somewhat hot. Again, not an issue with Windows 7.
- Instead of showing me the name of my ATI graphics card, it shows "standard" or "generic" display drivers. (Pardon me, I cannot recall the exact name.)
- The battery drains twice as fast as it does on Windows 7.

Other than the problems I have mentioned above, it works really good. No issue on software side at all.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to have a look over here - [How do I get AMD/Intel Hybrid Graphics drivers to work?](https://askubuntu.com/q/205112/35775)

---

Your laptop has dual grphics card. Unless you install drivers, both are on at same time and consuming battery. You can replicate the same on windows if you play games.

- To recognize your driver you should install `mesa-utlis` pkg

  - `sudo apt-get install mesa-utils`

Hybrid graphics in ubuntu (and in linux) is still a nightmare till now.

I don't have personal experience with ATI hybrid so all these are not tested by me.

**Option1:** Please check in BIOS, whether you can turnoff the discrete GPU (or intel one as you preferred).

If you can't disable it from BIOS (which is most possible case because of new GPU), you should follow the discussion and wiki pages very carefully to enable hybrid graphics.

- The link to ubuntu forum describe the process to 12.04 → [click here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1930450) . Please read the instruction very carefully.
- You might look for [changes for downloading in 12.10 version of ATI driver](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Quantal_Installation_Guide)

[Only the binary file got changed]