# how do I know if my laptop support switchable graphics and how to switch to it?

Tags: graphics, intel-graphics

I am having issues installing the ati drivers on my laptop; just wanted to know a way if my laptop support switchable graphics so that I can switch to integrated graphic card for better experience on ubuntu-graphics.

----------Hardware Specification-------------

```
sockets@ankit:/tmp$ lspci  | grep -i VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Seymour [Radeon HD 6400M Series]
```

The above results show that I also have integrated `Intel VGA controller`; how can I switch to this graphic card permanently if it is well supported by Ubuntu?

Comment: If my laptop has switchable graphics hardware; if it does how to switch to another graphics card.

Comment: if `lspci | grep VGA` return two devices then you have two graphics card. For switching and installation of card search this site with your graphics card model you will get guide.

Comment: @Web-E, sir you can add your comment as an answer. I've been able to install the intel integrated graphics card driver and i am on unity 3d. Thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `lspci | grep VGA` return two devices then you have two graphics card.

For switching and installation of correct drivers please follow-

[How do I get AMD/Intel Hybrid Graphics drivers to work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205112/ubuntu-12-10-amd-intel-hybrid-graphics-not-working)