# Ubuntu 13.04 AMD/Intel Hybrid Graphics not working

Tags: ati, 13.04, intel-graphics, fglrx, hybrid-graphics

With 12.10 I was able to use the solution provided in [How do I get AMD/Intel Hybrid Graphics drivers to work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205112/ubuntu-12-10-amd-intel-hybrid-graphics-not-working/210565#210565)

How to make it work in 13.04 Raring Ringtail?