# How to use Integrated GPU for Hybrid Laptop Intel/ATI?

Tags: dual-boot, ati, intel-graphics, lenovo, hybrid-graphics

So here's the problem, I have Lenovo Laptop Y460 equipped with Hybrid GPU that is an Intel Integrated GPU and an ATI Radeon HD 5650 as Discrete GPU. Basically I can switch the GPU either by switching the button in the laptop or directly from the software program.

hxxp://i.stack.imgur.com/Xg6cu.png

What annoy me is when I install Ubuntu as Dualboot alongside my windows 7, and once I boot to Ubuntu; The Discrete GPU turn on automatically. I don't like it cause I don't need it and the worst is it could drain my battery and overheat my laptop till it get shut down automatically.

So what did I do? I read a ton of post/article about this switching thing. This led me try these "How-to in step by step"
hxxp://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1930450
hxxp://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Quantal_Installation_Guide

1. I try to install ATI Catalyst driver 3 times but eventually it failed when I reboot it.
   The result is

   hxxp://i.stack.imgur.com/Y1A2S.jpg
   hxxp://i.stack.imgur.com/8VQyh.jpg

So I choose the first option "*Running in low graphics session*". But unfortunately when I got into desktop view, everything is blank including the dock and taskbar except the purple background color of ubuntu and the system also give a notice "*System is corrupt*"

While for the case of "**Linux Mint**", when I boot into Linux Mint - My view become Command Line Interface instead of GUI. The system also give a notice "*XOR Server fail to start*".

2.Another way is I try to switch off the Discrete GPU from BIOS, but sadly there is no option for Integrated GPU under the "**Graphics tab**". Instead the option is only 2, either switchable graphic or Discrete GPU.

So here I am, Now I'm stuck - don't know what to do. Could you help me how to solve it? (my purpose is I just want to use the Integrated GPU).

Lenovo IdeaPad Y460 Specifications:

- 14.0" HD Wide LED 1366x768
- Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit
- Intel Core i5 520M processor (2.40GHz, 3MB cache)
- ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5650 with 1GB VRAM and Intel GMA HD Switchable Graphics
- 4GB DDR3-1066 RAM (2x 2GB)
- 500GB 5400RPM hard drive (Seagate 5400.6)
- Intel Wireless Wi-Fi Link 1000BGN
- Built-in Bluetooth v2.1+EDR
- 8X DVD burner
- 6-cell Li-ion battery (11.1V, 57Wh)
- Weight: 4.98lbs
- Dimensions: 13.4 x 0.79–1.3 x 9.25 inches

Comment: I know Bumblebee is a project dedicated to this purpose, but I believe it's designed for NVIDIA chips. If you're ok with a little reading, check this out: http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-909802.html

Comment: Have tried this? [Ubuntu 12.10 AMD/Intel Hybrid Graphics not working](http://askubuntu.com/q/205112)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to start with the default open source driver... then try with vgaswitcheroo..

instructions here..

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics

I have a hybrid ATI/ATI graphics in my HP and both are enabled by default. using instructions from above I can disable the discrete graphics.. I still have to install this at boot and solve after suspend issues..but laptop is now cool to the touch