# Ubuntu 13.04 AMD/Intel Hybrid Graphics is not working

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, intel-graphics, 13.04

The same problem again, now for the newest release 13.04:

On 12.10 my Sony Vaio VPCSE with Intel® HD Graphics 3000 and AMD Radeon™ HD 6630M worked fine with the Catalyst Control Center, installed as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205112/ubuntu-12-10-amd-intel-hybrid-graphics-not-working/210565#210565).

But it is not working on Ubuntu 13.04 with the instructions, I described [in this entry](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205112/ubuntu-12-10-amd-intel-hybrid-graphics-not-working/210565#210565).

Comment: What is the issue? Can you give us some more info?