# Ubuntu 13.04 AMD/Intel Hybrid Switchable Graphics NOT WORKING!

Tags: ati, intel-graphics, 13.04, hybrid-graphics, switchable-graphics

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04 on the HP Pavilion dv7-6175us with AMD Radeon HD 6490M/Intel HD Graphics 3000 Switchable graphics. How can I make switchable graphics work on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

This guy's guide works: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1930450&page=76

> I've managed to install the fglrx driver and use the external graphics
>   adapter. The problem is the new intel graphics driver.
>
> Here's what I did:
>
> 1. Ensure that you have the deb files for the current AMD driver (created with --buildpkg as described in previous posts)
> 2. open a shell and download a previous version of the intel driver and it's dependencies:
>
>    ```
>    mkdir temp
>    cd temp
>    wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/119461148/libudev0_175-0ubuntu13_i386.deb
>    wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/111621162/xserver-xorg-video-intel_2.20.2-1ubuntu1_i386.deb
>    ```
> 3. remove the eventually installed fglrx and the installed intel drivers. When removing the intel driver let it remove both packages
>
>    ```
>    cd ..
>    sudo apt-get remove fglrx*
>    sudo apt-get remove xserver-xorg-video-intel
>    ```
> 4. install the older driver with its dependencies
>
>    ```
>    cd temp
>    sudo dpkg -i libudev*
>    sudo dpkg -i xserver-xorg-video-intel_2.20.2-1ubuntu1_i386.deb
>    ```
> 5. now install the fglrx packages (go to the folder containing the fglrx deb files). Warnings about defect link groups can be ignored (at least I did)
>
>    ```
>    cd <your folder with fglrx drivers>
>    sudo dpkg -i fglrx*.deb
>    ```
> 6. backup and remove the existing xorg.conf
>
>    ```
>    sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.backup
>    ```
> 7. create a new config file and switch to the external graphics adapter
>
>    ```
>    sudo aticonfig --px-dgpu
>    sudo aticonfig --initial -f
>    ```
> 8. reboot

That said, for 64-bit I had to pull the files from other sources than the ones listed in the post. Then in synaptic I locked the Intel drivers so they could not upgrade.

Comment: I find this doesn't work with the integrated card.  You get tearing effects and no external display support.

Comment: I dont think theres a way to get both to work, i never use the intel gpu

Comment: This: http://askubuntu.com/questions/205112/how-do-i-get-amd-intel-hybrid-graphics-drivers-working?lq=1 works for me