# xorg-video-abi-13 dependency problem

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, xubuntu, 13.04

I'm trying to install the ATI driver for my Probook 4540s (3000/7650M) according to instructions given in [How do I get AMD/Intel Hybrid Graphics drivers to work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205112/how-do-i-get-amd-intel-hybrid-graphics-drivers-working/288355#288355). After execute the following command:

```
sudo dpkg -i xserver-xorg-video-intel_2.21.6-0ubuntu4_amd64.deb
```

I get error:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xserver-xorg-video-intel:
xserver-xorg-video-intel depends on xorg-video-abi-13; however:
  Package xorg-video-abi-13 is not installed.
dpkg: error processing xserver-xorg-video-intel (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

What do I have to do to install the ATI driver properly? Are there any dependencies to use during installation?