# HDMI audio not working on hybrid graphics

Tags: drivers, sound, ati, hdmi, hybrid-graphics

I have an HP Pavilion dv6 laptop with Intel Sandybridge HD3000 / Ati Radeon 6490M switchable graphics. I am not very experienced in Ubuntu or Linux in general but I have installed 13.04 64bit, because I am hoping to switch from being a long-term Windows user. Everything seems to be working apart from audio over HDMI. I know there are no hardware problems because it works on Windows 7 64bit.

From a fresh install, none of the drivers suggested to me automatically work, so I used the method here: [How do I get AMD/Intel Hybrid Graphics drivers to work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205112/how-do-i-get-amd-intel-hybrid-graphics-drivers-to-work) and managed to install the solution offered for 13.04.

For all the proposed solutions, I can get video through HDMI but no sound, but for the above method even the video is buggy through HDMI.

At no point can I see HDMI sound output under sound settings.

Thank you in advance for your help.