# ATI video drivers issue

Tags: drivers, 13.04, ati

I recently installed ubuntu 13.04
I have a Radeon HD6470M and another intel integrated graphics card.
Under 'Additional Drivers' it says im using an open source driver for the Radeon HD 6400M/7400M series but when i look at the system details it says Intel® Sandybridge Mobile x86/MMX/SSE2 under graphics.

I have try'd to install the driver from AMD's site but that totally went wrong so i uninstalled it.

I am new to linux and ubuntu, does anyone know how i could fix this or find information?

Comment: So what do you want to do? Install the proprietary radeon drivers? Could you clarify?

Comment: I don't understand why i dont see my graphics card under system details, i don't know for sure if i have the correct drivers.

Comment: can you make sure that your monitor is plugged into your radeon card?

Comment: Do you have any **graphical problem**?

Comment: Never mind i fixed it by runnning `sudo apt-get install mesa-utils`, thanks for helping anywway

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to use **AMD proprietary driver** and **switch between AMD and Intel GPU** when necessary (e.g. using Intel GPU only when running on battery) you might like to have a look at this: **[How do I get AMD/Intel Hybrid Graphics drivers to work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205112/how-do-i-get-amd-intel-hybrid-graphics-drivers-to-work)**