# The system is running in low-graphics mode on hybrid gpu

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, intel-graphics

im running ubuntu 13.04 on my Sony VPCSB37_GA with intel and amd Graphic cards
I followed this [tutorial](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205112/how-do-i-get-amd-intel-hybrid-graphics-drivers-to-work) so i can switch between intel and amd and it was working good, till yesterday.
now i can only boot on intel, whenever i switch to amd by:

```
sudo aticonfig --xp-dgpu
```

and reboot, i get the "The system is running in low-graphics mode".
i am using the tty1 to run:

```
sudo aticonfig --xp-igpu
```

and get back to the intel card.
i don't know what happened, maybe because of an update?
i also re-installed everything from the same tutorial and re-installed ubuntu-desktop and lightdm but nothings works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest stable driver is not compatible with Ubuntu 13.04 yet. If you want to try the beta builder that has compatibility (in its changelog: http://support.amd.com/us/kbarticles/Pages/AMDCatalyst13-6LINBetaDriver.aspx). If you want to install, you can follow this tutorial with the beta driver:

Tutorial: [What is the correct way to install proprietary ATI Catalyst Video Drivers (fglrx) directly from AMD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx)

Driver: http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx