# Is lib32gcc1 exists in my system?

Tags: 13.04, 64-bit, package-management, dependencies, fglrx

I'm trying to istall AMD/Intel hybrid drivers using this [guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205112/how-do-i-get-amd-intel-hybrid-graphics-drivers-to-work) and have problem with 
lib32gcc1 when I'm try to install fglrx*.deb's `sudo dpkg -i fglrx*.deb`. 
I get dependency problems with it:

```
 dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of fglrx:
 fglrx depends on lib32gcc1; however:
  Package lib32gcc1 is not installed.
 fglrx depends on libc6-i386; however:
  Package libc6-i386 is not installed.
```

It says "Package lib32gcc1 is not installed." but look:

```
sudo apt-cache search lib32gcc1
lib32gcc1 - GCC support library (32 bit Version)
lib32gcc1-dbg - GCC support library (debug symbols)
```

then I'm tried:

```
sudo apt-get install lib32gcc1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 lib32gcc1 : Depends: libc6-i386 (>= 2.2.4) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

also

```
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get install lib32gcc1
```

don't help.

What is the problem? 
Is lib32gcc1 exists or not?
If it don't exists how can I get it to provide installation of fglrx*.deb's?

Comment: As an FYI, `sudo apt-cache search` doesn't just search installed plugins, it searches the entire package list for a given string.  So... yeah, just because it's listed in `apt-cache search` doesn't mean it's installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved problem with installing Catalyst driver using [this tutorial](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-fglrx/286775#286775).
It seems like correct way to install all dependencies including lib32gcc1 is:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential cdbs dh-make dkms execstack dh-modaliases linux-headers-generic fakeroot libqtgui4 lib32gcc1
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things to try:

1. Run `dpkg --print-architecture` and see what it outputs.  On a 64-bit Intel/AMD system, this should print `amd64`.
2. Run `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures` and see what it outputs.  It should print `i386`
3. If you *doesn't* print i386 for the previous step, run `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386` which should allow you to install 32-bit versions of things like libc6-i386

Comment: dpkg --print-architecture prints amd64,dpkg --print-foreign-architectures prints i386 but output of sudo apt-get install lib32gcc1 is still same. Thank you.