# Ubuntu 13.04 amd/intel hybrid graphics dual screen problems

Tags: 13.04, ati, multiple-monitors, fglrx, hybrid-graphics

After switching to Ubuntu 13.04 64bit, AMD proprietary drivers stopped working on my laptop with AMD/Intel hybrid graphics.

I tried installing older version of Intel graphics as described in this thread [How do I get AMD/Intel Hybrid Graphics drivers to work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205112/how-do-i-get-amd-intel-hybrid-graphics-drivers-to-work).

This solution works great with one monitor, but when I try to connect second one while using discrete card, my screen starts flickering and glitching very hard. It's hard to explain, seems like it tries to intersect two screens.

I noticed, that command `sudo aticonfig --set-pcs-str="DDX,EnableRandR12,FALSE"` failed to deactivate RandR1.2, so there's no Display Manager in amdcccle. I tried to search a solution for disabling RandR, but found none working.

I had none of these problems on Ubuntu 12.10 64bit.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What is the output of `lspci`? Why you want to use this drivers? Otherwise this will probably closed as dupe of the very same question you linked, since we don't know what difference has your pc from the linked question one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue. After some digging, I came to this solution that works for me:

```
xrandr --output LVDS1 --auto --right-of VGA1 --output VGA1 --auto --scale 1x1
```

In my case, I want to my laptop screen (LVDS1) to stand in the right of my external monitor (VGA).

You should replace LVDS1 and VGA1 with your own device ids.

You can find them by typing the command:

```
xrandr -q
```

Comment: The output for the two screens is right now with your xrandr-command but the flickering will not be solved.

Comment: I'm also seeing the same thing with 15.10 -- the xrandr command fixes some things, but the flickering persists...

Answer (score 0):

This is likely caused by the solution here: [How do I get AMD/Intel Hybrid Graphics drivers to work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205112/how-do-i-get-amd-intel-hybrid-graphics-drivers-to-work?rq=1) which forces outdated intel/libudev packages.

Comment: Please don't add comments as answers. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges) to upvote answers you like, or to add actual comments when seeking clarification of any issues. If you have a new question please [ask it](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask).