# How to get Ubuntu to stop heating up so much

Tags: reboot, overheating, process, fan, temperature

I already have another post on how to control the fans, but I was wondering if I am doing anything to cause this.  Ubuntu is running great at the beginning but after about twenty minutes of running temp goes from about 110 degrees F to 190 degrees F.

Even if I quit all programs the temp stays at the higher temp.
I have checked process list and nothing seems out of the ordinary.  The main programs that I run before this happens are Clementine, Firefox Nightly, Cairo-Dock (no OpenGL), and Gnome-System-Monitor.

The only thing that I have found to help is to reboot.
Then I start the process all over again.  By the way, I have a laptop cooler that it is also on.  I'm pretty sure it would overheat on me if I didn't have that.  I have had it get hot so far but I think the max temp is 225 degrees F.  I'm not too worried but it would be nice to have an answer.
Ubuntu (13.04) 
 GNOME Shell 3.6.3.1

 Fujitsu Lifebook AH530

Answer (score 0):

You may try to reduce load indeed. Start with tools like `top` or `htop` to determine which processes are straining the netbook the most and decide if all of them are necessary (some unnecessary or unwanted services are turned on by default). A more detailed answer could come if you post more info on culprits of (possible) high load.

Are you sure though that the OS is the cause of this? I didn't work with this particular model, but apparently according to reviewers at [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0047E1C2U) it frequently overheats. I don't think help with hardware is on topic in here and possible solutions depend very much on whether the machine is still within the vendor warranty period (as I guess you would not like to void the warranty).

Comment: Oh yeah.  I have run Windows for years on this laptop and have only had a problem if the vents are covered up. But it looks like it was Clementine that was the culprit.  It has an idiotic "mood" bar that it was trying to analyse a few thousand songs constantly.  It continues to do this in the background even after you close it.  I am still positive though that my fans are not operating correctly with Ubuntu, though.  I will just wait for a response on my other question regarding fan control.  I greatly appreciate your prompt response.

Answer (score 0):

On my experience, default setup of Ubuntu is very powerfull, but it is tweaked at performance. You can do some steps going the powersafe direction described here ([Heating issues and Fan sound on Dell Inspiron 3521 running Ubuntu 13.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/313682/heating-issues-and-fan-sound-on-dell-inspiron-3521-running-ubuntu-13-04))

Answer (score 0):

I have an Inspiron 14z with a Core i7 processor. I installed Ubuntu 12.04 in December 2012. It first ran fine. Later, however, it started crashing once per month, later once per week, and finally 2 times per day.

How to diagnose/solve the problem:

#### Way A:

On cold start, go to DELL diagnostics. When I ran those, my system crashed but before it did it displayed a note that the system is reaching a temperature of 100C and gave an error message. I searched that error message and DELL said:

1. Replace the fan, and
2. Update the BIOS.

I did both.

#### Way B:

Install `psensor`. Start `psensor`. Install a utility called “`stress`” on Ubuntu. Start it by `stress -c <number of cpu you have>`.  Watch the `psensor`. The good behavior is that the CPU utilization goes to 100% immediately, then the temp increases in form of 1 – e^(-t/T), which is a curve that looks like a charging capacitor. Just before it hits the maximum temperature, your CPU can handle (for Inspiron 14z it is 100C), then Ubuntu will reduce the frequency, which will reduce the temperature. The shape of the temperature looks like e^(-t/T), meaning like a discharging capacitor. If Ubuntu does it's job, you should observe this charging/discharging cycle every few minutes. If your cooling hardware is bad, then it will crash. If Ubuntu driver is not doing the right job, the computer will crash.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem, when I close Clementine on the Desktop, it still runs in the background overheating the CPU.  I have to **open a terminal and kill the application**. Perhaps that will help you also. I don't know a permanent fix for this.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, Controlling the CPU usage cooled the system down.

[Is there a way to autostart CPULIMIT in order to reduce excessive CPU consumption](https://askubuntu.com/questions/633794/is-there-a-way-to-autostart-cpulimit-in-order-to-reduce-excessive-cpu-consumptio)

Also this is a good post:

[Ways to keep your laptop cool](http://itsfoss.com/reduce-overheating-laptops-linux/)