# Is there a way to autostart CPULIMIT in order to reduce excessive CPU consumption

Tags: 14.04, bash, scripts, overheating, cpu-load

tracker-miner-f, tracker-store, tracker-extract and dropbox processes are killing my CPU, they make it run at over 100%, overheating my laptop.

I have installed CPULIMIT and it works great restricting these processes, however, I cannot get it to autostart.

I have followed [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=992706) but it does not work, the daemon starts but I think there is an error in the creation of the script and it does not actually limit any processes.

Is there a way to reduce cpu usage without having to manually do it through terminal every time I start a new session?

Ubuntu 14.04

A script I have found below, only partly runs and does not detect the PID correctly.

If someone has better knowledge than me, could you check the line:

```
NEW_PIDS_COMMAND="top -b -n1 -c | grep -E '$BLACK_PROCESSES_LIST' | gawk '\$9>CPU_LIMIT {print \$1}' CPU_LIMIT=$CPU_LIMIT"
```

Is this correct?

```
#!/bin/bash
# ==============================================================
# CPU limit daemon - set PID's max. percentage CPU consumptions
# ==============================================================

# Variables
CPU_LIMIT=40        # Maximum percentage CPU consumption by each PID
DAEMON_INTERVAL=3   # Daemon check interval in seconds
BLACK_PROCESSES_LIST="dropbox" # Limit only processes defined in this variable. If variable is empty (default) all violating processes are limited.
WHITE_PROCESSES_LIST=  # Limit all processes except processes defined in this variable. If variable is empty (default) all violating processes are limited.

#PID Variables
NEW_PIDS_COMMAND=       
NEW_PIDS=
LIMITED_PIDS=
QUEUE_PIDS=

# Check if both of the variables BLACK_PROCESSES_LIST or WHITE_PROCESSES_LIST are defined.
if [[ -n "$BLACK_PROCESSES_LIST" &&  -n "$WHITE_PROCESSES_LIST" ]]
then    
# If both variables are defined then error is produced.
   echo "At least one or both of the variables BLACK_PROCESSES_LIST or WHITE_PROCESSES_LIST must be empty."
   exit 1

# If Black_Processes_List is defined
elif [[ -n "$BLACK_PROCESSES_LIST" ]]
then  
# Set NEW_PIDS_COMMAND variable to below command
NEW_PIDS_COMMAND="top -b -n1 -c | grep -E '$BLACK_PROCESSES_LIST' | gawk '\$9>CPU_LIMIT {print \$1}' CPU_LIMIT=$CPU_LIMIT"

# If White_Processes_List is defined
elif [[ -n "$WHITE_PROCESSES_LIST" ]]   
then                                 
# Set NEW_PIDS_COMMAND variable to below command
   NEW_PIDS_COMMAND="top -b -n1 -c | gawk 'NR>6' | grep -E -v '$WHITE_PROCESSES_LIST' | gawk '\$9>CPU_LIMIT {print \$1}' CPU_LIMIT=$CPU_LIMIT"

else
   NEW_PIDS_COMMAND="top -b -n1 -c | gawk 'NR>6 && \$9>CPU_LIMIT {print \$1}' CPU_LIMIT=$CPU_LIMIT"
fi

# Search and limit violating PIDs
while sleep $DAEMON_INTERVAL
do
   NEW_PIDS=$(eval "$NEW_PIDS_COMMAND")                                                                    # Violating PIDs
   LIMITED_PIDS=$(ps -eo args | gawk '$1=="cpulimit" {print $3}')                                          # Already limited PIDs
   QUEUE_PIDS=$(comm -23 <(echo "$NEW_PIDS" | sort -u) <(echo "$LIMITED_PIDS" | sort -u) | grep -v '^$')   # PIDs in queue

   for i in $QUEUE_PIDS
   do
       cpulimit -p $i -l $CPU_LIMIT -z &   # Limit new violating processes
   done
done
```

I only want to black list specific applications so I have altered to this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# CPU limit of a process
#
# Variables
CPU_LIMIT=50        # Maximum percentage CPU consumption by each PID 
                    # NOTE: If your machine has one processor you can limit the percentage from 0% to 100%, which means that if you set for example 50%, your process cannot use more than 500 ms of cpu time for each second. But if your machine has four processors, percentage may vary from 0% to 400%, so setting the limit to 200% means to use no more than half of the available power.
DAEMON_INTERVAL=3   # Daemon check interval in seconds
PROCESS_1="" # Processes to be limited. If variable is empty (default) all violating processes are limited.


if [ -n "$PROCESS_1" ] # Process_1 entered
then  

    PID_1="pidof $PROCESS_1" # Set NEW_PIDS_COMMAND variable to below command

echo "Limit Process of: $PROCESS_1"

    cpulimit --pid "$PID_1" -b -l "$CPU_LIMIT" # Run cpulimit with selected paramters

else

   echo "All Processes limited to: $CPU_LIMIT"

   PID_1="top -b -n1 -c | gawk 'NR>6 && \$9>CPU_LIMIT {print \$1}' CPU_LIMIT=$CPU_LIMIT" # Set global CPU limit
fi


# Search and limit violating PIDs
while sleep $DAEMON_INTERVAL
do
   NEW_PIDS=$(eval "$PID_1")                                                                    # Violating PIDs
   LIMITED_PIDS=$(ps -eo args | gawk '$1=="cpulimit" {print $3}')                                          # Already limited PIDs
   QUEUE_PIDS=$(comm -23 <(echo "$NEW_PIDS" | sort -u) <(echo "$LIMITED_PIDS" | sort -u) | grep -v '^$')   # PIDs in queue

   for i in $QUEUE_PIDS
   do
       cpulimit -p $i -l $CPU_LIMIT -z &   # Limit new violating processes
   done
done
```

This works, but how do I limit multiple processes? At the moment it is either one or all ... Thanks

Comment: "the daemon starts but I think there is an error in the creation of the script and it does not actually limit any processes." why no t focus on fixing this? see your log files in /var/log/ and track down the error.

Comment: yeah easier said than done my friend... I have been trying to work out why the the line : BLACK_PROCESSES_LIST=   # Limit only processes defined in this variable. If variable is empty (default) all violating processes are limited....... Does not actually do anything, yet running  the 'cpulimit' directly in terminal does... I am trying to work out how to create a script to run the terminal commands at boot... All new to me :)

Comment: What is your CPU governor set to? See `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_governor`.

Comment: The script works as expected on my system. Is there a `dropbox` process running and taking up >40% CPU on your system? Please [edit] your question and include the output of `ps -aux | grep dropbox` showing the offending process.

Comment: My CPU Governor is set to POWERSAVE

Comment: I have altered the script and it works now on my system, TOP showing CPU limited and laptop running cooler. However, I haven't worked out how to limit more than one process. The way it works at the moment is it will limit either one process or all of them....   Thanks

Comment: gratz @pst007x make it an answer though ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I have done to resolve my issue:

```
sudo apt-get install cpulimit ; sudo apt-get install gawk ; sudo apt-get install top
```

Then I altered a script to suit:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    # CPU limit of a process
    #
    # Variables
    # NOTE: If your machine has one processor you can limit the percentage from 0% to 100%, which means that if you set for example 50%, your process cannot use more than 500 ms of cpu time for each second. But if your machine has four processors, percentage may vary from 0% to 400%, so setting the limit to 200% means to use no more than half of the available power.

    CPU_LIMIT_1=50    # Maximum percentage CPU consumption by PROCESS_1
    CPU_LIMIT_2=55    # Maximum percentage CPU consumption by PROCESS_2
    CPU_LIMIT_3=60    # Maximum percentage CPU consumption by PROCESS_3
    CPU_LIMIT_4=40    # Maximum percentage CPU consumption by PROCESS_4
    PROCESS_1="dropbox"  # Process 1 to be limited. If variable 1 is empty (default) all violating processes are limited.
    PROCESS_2="tracker-miner-f"   # Process 2 to be limited
    PROCESS_3="tracker-store"   # Process 3 to be limited
    PROCESS_4="tracker-extract"   # Process 4 to be limited
    PROCESS_5="chrome"   # Process 5 to be limited

    gnome-terminal -x top

    if [ -n "$PROCESS_1" ] || [ -n "$PROCESS_2" ] || [ -n "$PROCESS_3" ] || [ -n "$PROCESS_4" ] || [ -n "$PROCESS_5" ] ; then
      while true;
        do  
        echo "Limit the Process of: $PROCESS_1 to $CPU_LIMIT_1"
            cpulimit --exe "$PROCESS_1" -b -l "$CPU_LIMIT_1"
            sleep 3 
        echo "Limit the Process of: $PROCESS_2 to $CPU_LIMIT_1"
            cpulimit --exe "$PROCESS_2" -b -l "$CPU_LIMIT_1"
            sleep 3   
        echo "Limit the Process of: $PROCESS_3 to $CPU_LIMIT_1"
            cpulimit --exe "$PROCESS_3" -b -l "$CPU_LIMIT_1"
            sleep 3  
        echo "Limit the Process of: $PROCESS_4 to $CPU_LIMIT_1"
            cpulimit --exe "$PROCESS_4" -b -l "$CPU_LIMIT_1"
            sleep 3 
        echo "Limit the Process of: $PROCESS_5 to $CPU_LIMIT_3"
            cpulimit --exe "$PROCESS_5" -b -l "$CPU_LIMIT_4"
            sleep 60
     done       

    else
       echo "Process fields empty"
    fi
  exit 1
```

Created a folder in my home menu called it start and moved the script there.

I want to run it when I wanted so I created a launcher using 'menulibre' with the option to run in terminal.

There may be a better way, but for now this works... any better solutions welcome!

Thanks

Also this for restricting an individual process or global:

```
#!/bin/bash
# CPU limit of a process of one application or set global limit
#
# 
DAEMON_INTERVAL=3   # Daemon check interval in seconds

 gnome-terminal -x top

read -p "Do you want to set global CPU limitations y or n : " y

if test "$y" = "y" ; then

    read -p "Enter Global CPU limit :" CPU_LIMIT_ALL 
    echo $'\nAll Processes shall be limited to:' $CPU_LIMIT_ALL 

 while true
      do
       PID_1="top -b -n1 -c | awk 'NR>6 && \$9>CPU_LIMIT_ALL {print \$1}' CPU_LIMIT_ALL=$CPU_LIMIT_ALL"       # Set global CPU limit reads TOP list 
       NEW_PIDS=$(eval "$PID_1")                                                                               # Violating PIDs
       LIMITED_PIDS=$(ps -eo args | gawk '$1=="cpulimit" {print $3}')       
                                          # Already limited PIDs                                                   
       QUEUE_PIDS=$(comm -23 <(echo "$NEW_PIDS" | sort -u) <(echo "$LIMITED_PIDS" | sort -u) | grep -v '^$')   # PIDs in queue

   for i in $QUEUE_PIDS
      do
       cpulimit -p "$i" -l "$CPU_LIMIT_ALL" -z &   # Limit new violating processe 
 done
done

elif test "$y" = "n" ; then

    read -p  "Enter process to be restricted or press enter :" r
    read -p  "Enter value of CPU limit or press enter :" l

   while true
    do
     echo $'\nProcess Entry Found' 
     echo $'CPU Entry Found\n'

     echo "Limit the Process of: $r to $l"  

     cpulimit --exe "$r" -b -l "$l" -z &                    # Set CPU limit for process
     sleep 60
 done

else
  echo "No input found" 
  exit 1
fi
```

Save as a .sh then make executable and run [tutorial](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/run-execute-sh-shell-script/)

If you need to you can also run the scripts as root to restrict all system processes too.

sudo /path/to/script/

Answer (score 5):

I realize this thread is a bit old; however, there is a *much* easier way to accomplish your stated goal.  Using the processes and limits you seem to desire, you can simply create a shell script such as:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Set this variable to the number of cores in your processor.  This example is for an 8-core CPU.  The reason that the number of cores is important is that you need to take it into consideration when setting cpulimit's -l option.  This is explained on the cpulimit project page (see http://cpulimit.sourceforge.net/):  "If your machine has one processor you can limit the percentage from 0% to 100%, which means that if you set for example 50%, your process cannot use more than 500 ms of cpu time for each second. But if your machine has four processors, percentage may vary from 0% to 400%, so setting the limit to 200% means to use no more than half of the available power."

NUM_CPU_CORES=8 #Change this number to reflect the number of cores in your processor.

cpulimit -e "dropbox" -l $((50 * $NUM_CPU_CORES))& #Limit "dropbox" process to 50% CPU usage.
cpulimit -e "tracker-miner-f" -l $((50 * $NUM_CPU_CORES))& #Limit "tracker-miner-f" process to 50% CPU usage.
cpulimit -e "tracker-store" -l $((50 * $NUM_CPU_CORES))& #Limit "tracker-store" process to 50% CPU usage.
cpulimit -e "tracker-extract" -l $((50 * $NUM_CPU_CORES))& #Limit "tracker-extract" process to 50% CPU usage.
cpulimit -e "chrome" -l $((40 * $NUM_CPU_CORES))& #Limit "chrome" process to 40% CPU usage.
```

Make the above script executable and set it to auto-run as you did with your other scripts (get rid of the other scripts).  In effect, *cpulimit* will stay in the background and watch for the specified processes and, as soon as one is started, *cpulimit* will take control and effect its specified limit.  When a specified process dies or is killed, *cpulimit* will watch for it to become active again, and the process repeats.

Comment: I suggest the first line to be `NUM_CPU_CORES=$(nproc --all)`

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to start the program automatically on startup, you can add it to your startup applications. See the following answer for more information.

[How do I start applications automatically on login?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48321/how-do-i-start-applications-automatically-on-login/48327#48327)