# Catalyst on Ubuntu 13.04 hybrid graphics supporting dual screen?

Tags: drivers, graphics, multiple-monitors

anyone made double screen configuration works on Ubuntu 13.04 using Catalyst? I followed this guide [How do I get AMD/Intel Hybrid Graphics drivers to work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205112/how-do-i-get-amd-intel-hybrid-graphics-drivers-to-work)

I have tried several drivers (the latest beta and the latest stable ones) - did not succeed. Everything works until I turn on the second monitor. After that just flickering. If anybody has the working configuration, please, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

There is a temporary solution http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2149791