# Configuring switchable graphics

Tags: drivers, 15.04, graphics, ati

My laptop has both Intel and AMD graphics cards:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Chelsea LP [Radeon HD 7730M] (rev ff)
```

I have the following AMD driver installed in my laptop:

`Using X.Org X server - AMD/ATI display driver wrapper from xserver-xorg-video-ati (open source, tested)`

Is there any way I can just press a button to switch between using the discreet graphics and just using the Intel card?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

i have same problem.
dell inspiron 7520
ubuntu 15.10

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Chelsea LP [Radeon HD 7730M] (rev ff)
```

sudo aticonfig --initial -f

No supported adapters detected

[try this](https://askubuntu.com/a/324793/532340)

> If you are using **multiple AMD graphics cards or AMD dual graphics** (i.e.: notebook users), use:
>
> **sudo amdconfig --adapter=all --initial**

Result:

```
Using /etc/X11/xorg.conf
Saving back-up to /etc/X11/xorg.conf.fglrx-0
```

> 11. The Catalyst Control Center should now offer a choice between the integrated Intel graphics and the dedicated AMD graphics. To switch,
>       select the graphics you want to run. Because the change is not
>       dynamic, a reboot is required.

...and use this [script](http://pastebin.com/DFsmFVCN)

```
cd ~
wget -c --referer='http://support.amd.com/ru-ru/download/desktop?os=Linux+x86_64' https://www2.ati.com/drivers/linux/radeon-crimson-15.12-15.302-151217a-297685e.zip
unzip radeon-crimson-15.12-15.302-151217a-297685e.zip
cd fglrx-15.302
sudo sh amd-driver-installer-15.302-x86.x86_64.run --buildandinstallpkg
sudo apt-get -fy install
sudo amdconfig --initial -f
cd ~
sudo rm -r fglrx-15.302
```

Answer (score 1):

You're currently running with the open-soured AMD driver, to switch to the Intel graphic card, a safer way is to install the proprietary AMD video driver to get this feature (search "Driver" in your dash). And you will be able to use the **AMD Catalyst Control Center** for it, which can be found from the dash as well:
[image: dash]

Which should allow you to switch between the Intel and the AMD GPU:
[image: AMDCCC]

Note that the system must be rebooted.