# How to uninstall Catalyst 13.8 beta?

Tags: 13.04, ati, uninstall, catalyst

I'm currently running 13.04 with the 3.10 kernel, so I can use my wifi.

I foolishly tried to use Catalyst 13.6 beta even though it says it's not compatible with kernel 3.10.

Still, I have my laptop right where I want and can't live without it, but I want to try to install Catalyst 13.8 beta since it's compatible with kernel 3.10.

If the install goes wrong, how can Catalyst 13.8 beta be uninstalled?

Comment: How did you install the drivers? From the Software Centre? Download from AMD and run the package? Build your own package deb packages? The uninstall process depends on how you installed it.

Comment: @Devi710 thanks for looking!  i followed this process exactly with high-gpu dual monitors http://askubuntu.com/a/288355/128334

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you built the deb packages yourself, the proper command is:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx*
```

You missed the "remove" and "--" parts in the previous command you tried. More information can be found here:
http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Raring_Installation_Guide#Removing_Catalyst.2Ffglrx

If you plan on using the open source drivers after run:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge xserver-xorg-video-ati xserver-xorg-video-radeon
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-ati
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri xserver-xorg-core
sudo mv /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.backup
sudo rm -rf /etc/ati
```

Answer (score 0):

The Ubuntu documentation on this is pretty helpful; see here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI

To summarize: first, download the drivers from AMD.
Next, install some packages needed to build from source, if you don't have them already:

```
sudo apt-get install dh-make dh-modaliases execstack libc6-i386 lib32gcc1
```

Then, instead of just running the install scripts to install directly, you can build .deb packages instead, by running

```
sh amd-driver-installer-catalyst-13-4-x86.x86_64.run --buildpkg Ubuntu/raring
```

You can then install the packages (there should be three of them) using gdebi or synaptic (or the software centre, I suppose), or from the command prompt using

```
sudo dpkg -i fglrx*.deb
```

Finally, type `sudo aticonfig --initial` (or equivalently - I think - `sudo amdconfig --initial`), and then reboot.
If the drivers don't work according to plan, you can remove them as you would other software. (I find this is most easily accomplished using synaptic, and typing fglrx into the search bar, since the software centre doesn't like to let you see "technical" items, or you could run apt-get remove for the file names created when you built the .deb packages.)

Answer (score -1):

Here ya go:

```
/usr/share/ati/
sudo ./amd-uninstall.sh
```

Comment: why does this answer has downvotes, without any conmment explaining what is wrong about it?