# ubuntu 13.04, kde 4.11, ati fglrx 13.8 beta - opengl doesn't work

Tags: 13.04, ati, fglrx, opengl, kwin

I have just upgraded to ubuntu 13.04 with kernel 3.10.6. After that I have updated my fglrx to 13.8 beta and after that I have added ppa:kubuntu-ppa/backports and I have upgraded my system.
After reboot my effects settings changed to xrander, so I tried to apply new opengl 2.1,2.0 and 3.1 but none of them works. It says that "it was not possible to activate effects using those options, check the X configuration or change the options about the composition type".

Here is my **xorg.conf**:
http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=D6MPUEZv

and my **Xorg.0.log**:
http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=nXF80qmH

This is the output of **glxinfo**:

```
name of display: :0
Setting of real/effective user Id to 0/0 failed
libGL error: open uki failed (Operation not permitted)
libGL error: reverting to (slow) indirect rendering
display: :0  screen: 0
direct rendering: No (If you want to find out why, try setting LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose)
server glx vendor string: ATI
server glx version string: 1.4
server glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap,
    GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_OML_swap_method,
    GLX_SGI_make_current_read, GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_SGIS_multisample,
    GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group
client glx vendor string: ATI
client glx version string: 1.4
client glx extensions:
    GLX_ARB_create_context, GLX_ARB_create_context_profile,
    GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_import_context,
    GLX_EXT_swap_control, GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating,
    GLX_MESA_allocate_memory, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, GLX_MESA_swap_control,
    GLX_MESA_swap_frame_usage, GLX_NV_swap_group, GLX_OML_swap_method,
    GLX_SGI_make_current_read, GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_SGI_video_sync,
    GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer,
    GLX_SGIX_swap_barrier, GLX_SGIX_swap_group, GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group,
    GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB,
    GLX_ARB_fbconfig_float, GLX_AMD_gpu_association, GLX_EXT_buffer_age
GLX version: 1.4
GLX extensions:
    GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_import_context,
    GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_OML_swap_method,
    GLX_SGI_make_current_read, GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_SGIS_multisample,
    GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group,
    GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap
OpenGL vendor string: ATI Technologies Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon HD 6800 Series
OpenGL version string: 2.1 (4.3.12438 Compatibility Profile Context 13.20.5)
OpenGL shading language version string: (null)
OpenGL extensions:
    GL_ARB_depth_texture, GL_ARB_draw_buffers, GL_ARB_fragment_program,
    GL_ARB_fragment_program_shadow, GL_ARB_imaging, GL_ARB_multisample,
    GL_ARB_multitexture, GL_ARB_occlusion_query, GL_ARB_point_parameters,
    GL_ARB_point_sprite, GL_ARB_shadow, GL_ARB_shadow_ambient,
    GL_ARB_texture_border_clamp, GL_ARB_texture_compression,
    GL_ARB_texture_cube_map, GL_ARB_texture_env_add,
    GL_ARB_texture_env_combine, GL_ARB_texture_env_crossbar,
    GL_ARB_texture_env_dot3, GL_ARB_texture_mirrored_repeat,
    GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two, GL_ARB_texture_rectangle,
    GL_ARB_transpose_matrix, GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object,
    GL_ARB_vertex_program, GL_ARB_window_pos, GL_ARB_shader_objects,
    GL_ARB_vertex_shader, GL_ARB_fragment_shader, GL_ARB_framebuffer_object,
    GL_ARB_geometry_shader4, GL_EXT_abgr, GL_EXT_bgra, GL_EXT_blend_color,
    GL_EXT_blend_equation_separate, GL_EXT_blend_func_separate,
    GL_EXT_blend_minmax, GL_EXT_blend_subtract, GL_EXT_copy_texture,
    GL_EXT_draw_range_elements, GL_EXT_fog_coord, GL_EXT_framebuffer_object,
    GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays, GL_EXT_packed_pixels, GL_EXT_point_parameters,
    GL_EXT_rescale_normal, GL_EXT_secondary_color,
    GL_EXT_separate_specular_color, GL_EXT_shadow_funcs, GL_EXT_stencil_wrap,
    GL_EXT_subtexture, GL_EXT_texture3D, GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc,
    GL_EXT_texture_edge_clamp, GL_EXT_texture_env_add,
    GL_EXT_texture_env_combine, GL_EXT_texture_env_dot3, GL_EXT_texture_lod,
    GL_EXT_texture_lod_bias, GL_EXT_texture_mirror_clamp,
    GL_EXT_texture_object, GL_EXT_texture_rectangle, GL_EXT_vertex_array,
    GL_EXT_histogram, GL_EXT_framebuffer_blit, GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample,
    GL_EXT_geometry_shader4, GL_EXT_gpu_shader4, GL_ATI_draw_buffers,
    GL_ATI_texture_env_combine3, GL_ATI_texture_mirror_once,
    GL_ATIX_texture_env_combine3, GL_IBM_texture_mirrored_repeat,
    GL_INGR_blend_func_separate, GL_SGIS_generate_mipmap,
    GL_SGIS_texture_border_clamp, GL_SGIS_texture_edge_clamp,
    GL_SGIS_texture_lod, GL_SGIX_shadow_ambient, GL_SUN_multi_draw_arrays,
    GL_ARB_texture_float
```

and this is the output of **fglrxinfo**:

```
Setting of real/effective user Id to 0/0 failed
libGL error: open uki failed (Operation not permitted)
libGL error: reverting to (slow) indirect rendering
display: :0  screen: 0
OpenGL vendor string: ATI Technologies Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon HD 6800 Series
OpenGL version string: 2.1 (4.3.12438 Compatibility Profile Context 13.20.5)
```

How can I solve it?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Your drivers are corrupted - there's a lot of bugs in 13.8, such as lack of access rights to procfs / proc / ati / ... are patches on it, but these drivers are highly "inappropriate" for example, memory leaks, etc.. : P I would recommend for now 13.3 beta3 - by our NeteXt'73 - I built Catalyst 13.3 beta3 v4 so, and would ideally operate under 3.10.x kernels, and my v25.x

http://ubuntu.pl/forum/viewtopic.php?f=216&t=163378

As to the KDE 4.11, have researched this situation - it looks like a bug in KWin.

Comment: ok it was not a kwin but, I have removed fglrx 13.8 and kernel 3.10. Now I have fglrx 13.4 stable and kernel 3.8 and everything works, also new kwin opengl v3.1.
So I will try NeteXt'73 driver 'cause as you said it works with kernel 3.10.x, thanks

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with 3.10 kernel, fglrx 13-8 beta, and kde 4.11. 
Here is what worked:

Run the driver installer with the extract option:

```
./amd-catalyst-13.8-beta1-linux-x86.x86_64.run --extract [dirname]`
```

Then `cd [dirname]` and open file "common/lib/modules/fglrx/build_mod/firegl_public.c". Find line 821 or 822. Change:

```
root = KCL_create_proc_dir(NULL, "ati", S_IFDIR);
```

...to:

```
root = KCL_create_proc_dir(NULL, "ati", S_IFDIR|S_IRUGO|S_IXUGO);
```

Then run this and reboot:

```
sudo ./ati-installer --arguments --install
```

...or rebuild deb packages, install them then reboot:

```
sudo ./ati-installer --arguments --buildpkg Ubuntu/raring
```

<sub>**Source:** http://phoronix.com/forums/showthread.php?82948-AMD-Catalyst-13-8-Beta-Driver-For-Linux-Released/page6</sub>

Comment: thanks, I finally can see a complete explanation of the patch installation thanks.
but maybe it would be better to wait for a stable release

Comment: i can confirm that this has cleared up all issues for me and has allowed me to run cinnamon: 13.04, 3.10, HD8400.  ty!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem (fglrx 13.4 / kubuntu 13.04 / kde 4.11 / kernel 3.8.0-29).

After reinstalling fglrx-updates package (from ubuntu repository) AND

```
sudo aticonfig --initial --force
```

and restart OpenGL worked again for me.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm this issue on my kubuntu 12.04 installation using the backports repository. I'm using the fglrx-driver which was suggested by jockey (I will post more information, when I'm at work tomorrow).

I previously ran 4.10 without having any problems. After receiving th 4.11 Update my Desktop effects (Opengl) won't run anymore. Working without effects I get a lot of fractals when I change size or doing somethin similar.

As intermediate solution I installed gnome shell. Mutter does not seem to have a problem with the fglrx driver due 3d is working as expected here.

Any suggestions what I can do?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Confirming same under KDE(buntu) 13.04 over 3.9 kernel + catalyst 13.8 beta driver on AMD A10 6800 APU with ATI Richland [Radeon HD 8670D] on 3 screens, one X, no xinerama.

I managed to have OpenGL running after dome voodoo dancing, not sure what helped in the end. Worked quite fast and nice, but there were problems with mentioned above fractals and crushing plasma.

I switched to XRender then, and it seem to be fine so far. Few effects not working though, but most of them do. The only drawback is that GTK apps run little slow (these do run fast under OpenGL).

Another issue was KWin and plasma-desktop eating CPU, but that was resolved by removing  "System monitor" widget.

Thanks for updating your post, I will try roll back to 3.8/13.4 too, when I need OpenGL.