# Unity is working but not visible after installing AMD Catalyst 13.8 Beta2

Tags: unity, 13.04, drivers, 64-bit, radeon

I have installed AMD Catalyst 13.8 Beta 2 Drivers

Now the Unity is working i can click the close button or maximize button or everything if i remember their locations they are nto visible :(

Some one please help me

Check this screenshot, the top and left corners are occupied by unity http://pbrd.co/16AA1Cf

I am aware that i can resolve this issue by removing AMD Drivers, i want to use the AMD Drivers, please help me resolve this issue (I installed using this procedure for Ubuntu 13.04 [How do I get AMD/Intel Hybrid Graphics drivers to work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205112/how-do-i-get-amd-intel-hybrid-graphics-drivers-to-work))

MY Card is AMD Radeon HD 6370M (6300M Series as stated in About dialog)

Comment: And your card is?

Comment: AMD Radeon HD 6300M

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall it and go back to 13.6. Sadly right now there are some serious xserver / xorg conflicts with 13.8. Also there has been talks of 13.9 floating around somewhere. Maybe give that a try?

I have been looking for a solution myself. While I got some things to fix it temporarily nothing really stuck for longer than a reboot. I would really like to jump up to 13.8. Although I have read that when running Xubuntu there have been less issues. I think I may jump to that ship.