# Ubuntu 13.04 display problem (Samsung ATIV Book 9 Lite)

Tags: ati, samsung

I'm into trouble for few days and I really need help.

So, I've got a new laptop (Samsung ATIV Book 9 Lite) and installed Ubuntu 13.04 (64bit). Now everything look good but my graphical display is very bad (launcher doesn't take opacity and always displaying 1px border-right even it's hidden, windows are very slow etc..).
Actually I'm not prof-tech-man and I'm just stuck!

Q: What I need to do any more or am missing?

Thanks in advance.

Here is some infos;

```
kerem@kerem:~$ sudo lshw -c video
*-display UNCLAIMED     
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Kabini [Radeon HD 8250]
   vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI
   physical id: 1
   bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
   version: 00
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d07fffff ioport:f000(size=256) memory:feb00000-feb3ffff memory:feb40000-feb5ffff
```

Seems not all OK;

```
kerem@kerem:~$ /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
OpenGL vendor string:   VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.2, 128 bits)
OpenGL version string:  2.1 Mesa 9.1.3

Not software rendered:    no
Not blacklisted:          yes
GLX fbconfig:             yes
GLX texture from pixmap:  yes
GL npot or rect textures: yes
GL vertex program:        yes
GL fragment program:      yes
GL vertex buffer object:  yes
GL framebuffer object:    yes
GL version is 1.4+:       yes

Unity 3D supported:       no
```

[image]

Also I saw this and: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/HybridGraphics

```
kerem@kerem:~$ dpkg -l fglrx\*
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
un  fglrx-glx      <none>                    (no description available)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install Catalyst.

For your card and kernel, you want [13.6](http://support.amd.com/us/kbarticles/Pages/AMDCatalyst13-6LINBetaDriver.aspx).

Follow [these directions](https://askubuntu.com/a/288355/128334) exactly, and you should be good to go.

Comment: @qeremy np!  was in the same predicament until i stumbled upon that answer via another q.  13.6 should be out of beta soon.

Comment: Hey! I used "AMD Catalyst™ 13.4 Proprietary Linux x86 Display Driver" not beta on this page (http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx) and everything OK. Thank you again! :)

Comment: @qeremy oh good!  didn't see your card on the list.