# Ubuntu 12.10 slow after fresh installation

Tags: installation, ati, graphics, radeon

I have installed Ubuntu 12.10 on my system with USB. After installation it seems that the system is slow. I think the problem is with its graphics card driver. The system that I am using is an HP Pavilion DV6 laptop with a Radeon HD 6400M/7400M ATI graphics card.

When I ran `lspci -nn | grep VGA` in the terminal the output was:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0116] (rev 09)  
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Seymour [Radeon HD 6400M/7400M Series] [1002:6760]
```

I already tried running `sudo apt-get install fglrx fglrx-amdcccle` and that made the Unity launcher disappear, so I reinstalled Ubuntu 12.10. How can I install the graphics driver for my HP Pavilion DV6 laptop without losing the Unity launcher?

**Update**

Now its showing X.org X server AMD/ATI dsplay driver. But still its showing slow and the laptop temperature is increasing and after sometime laptop goes to shutdown automatically.

Comment: yes so i re install 12.10 and now i have no graphics card activated

Answer (score 0):

are you using the open source drivers or the properiarity drivers from AMD?

if you are using the open source drivers try the one from AMD you can download from their site.
It will give you a big performance boost, but you will get updates not as fast as the open source drivers do.

Answer (score 0):

> when i used lspci -nn | grep VGA the out put was 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0116] (rev 09) 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Seymour [Radeon HD 6400M/7400M Series] [1002:6760]

This means your laptop has dual video cards, the one is the in built GPU that comes with your processor for low power GPU calculations and the other one is the dedicated GPU. You may want to use them both and switch which GPU to use according to what you need.

Follow the instructions [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205112/how-do-i-get-amd-intel-hybrid-graphics-drivers-to-work).