# How to install the amd Catalyst drivers in Ubuntu?

Tags: drivers, 13.10, catalyst

I am wondering has anyone had any luck installing the catalyst drivers on 13.10 and I have had some trouble in the past on 13.04 with kernel 3.10, and before I upgrade it would be nice know that everything will be in working order.

Comment: if your card isn't on this list https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver then you need to do this http://askubuntu.com/questions/205112/how-do-i-get-amd-intel-hybrid-graphics-drivers-to-work