# Black screen after installing the ATI driver

Tags: boot, drivers, ati

I'm new to the Linux world but decided to try Ubuntu and so far I like it.

But after installing the ATI driver a weird thing occured. Whenever I turn on my laptop, it starts normally up to the part where I can choose the OS I'd like to boot (with purple background) and when I hit Enter to boot the Ubuntu, it just beeps and stays black, nothing happens.

I tried to find a solution but got nothing so far.

When I boot in recovery mode (root) and try to purge the driver, 3 lines appear :

```
W: Not using locking for read only lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock
E: Unable  to write to /var/cache/apt/
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

It's like that will all commands I try.

I'd really like to use Ubuntu and maybe at some point I'll remove Windows entirely but for now it's just unusable.

I have a request, if someone replies, please try to explain everything step by step since I'm new to this.

P.S. I am really sorry if there is already a post answering to this.

Answer (score 0):

Install the `xserver-xorg-video-intel` and one of the `fglrx` packages from this [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~andrikos/+archive/ppa/+packages?field.name_filter=&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=quantal) should work.

for more information about your problem check [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205112/how-do-i-get-amd-intel-hybrid-graphics-drivers-to-work)

Comment: how do you know if him has hybrid intel/ati?

Answer (score 0):

Information about packages are stored in `/var/lib/dpkg/` folder.

This folder is is needed for any process that install or remove packages. In your case, this folder is being modified or being used by other process.

It is the reason for it is having a `lock` file.

So you need to identify that process and stop it to continue purging the driver package.

To identify the process based on file system, you can use the command [`fuser`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/fuser.1.html)

```
sudo fuser [OPTION] [FILE]
```

And kill the process you can use `-k` option with it.

```
sudo fuser -k /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

So because you need to stop that process somehow that cammand is enough. If you need to ask before to kill you can use `-i` option.

If you need to show the process before kill you can use `-v` option.