# Laptop temperature too high

Tags: drivers, radeon, overheating

I have a fresh install of ubuntu 12.04, My laptop temperature is too high 78.

Output of `lspci`:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM76 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Thames [Radeon HD 7500M/7600M Series]
07:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
07:00.1 Bluetooth: Ralink corp. RT3290 Bluetooth
08:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI 
Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 05)
09:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

*How to make the temperature low?*

The output of `sudo lshw -C display` is:

```
*-display               
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Thames [Radeon HD 7500M/7600M Series]
   vendor: Hynix Semiconductor (Hyundai Electronics)
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: 00
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
   resources: irq:48 memory:40000000-4fffffff memory:62000000-6201ffff 
ioport:4000(size=256) memory:62020000-6203ffff

*-display
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 09
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
   resources: irq:46 memory:63000000-633fffff  
   memory:50000000-5fffffff
   ioport:5000(size=64)
```

Can someone please help with this , What should be done so that temperature remain around 50, 
Should  some graphics be disabled?

Answer (score 0):

You can lower speed of CPU, it helps. Here is a script to auto lower speed of CPU when it reaches upper limit you choose. https://github.com/Sepero/temp-throttle/blob/master/temp_throttle.sh

Answer (score 0):

You have switchable graphics. If you don't need the extra performance from the discrete AMD graphics card then you can switch it off permanently in the BIOS of your laptop.

If your BIOS has no option for that or you need the extra performance, then please look up [this Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205112/how-do-i-get-amd-intel-hybrid-graphics-drivers-to-work) for solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I find battery saving applications help a lot for overheating. `laptop-mode-tools` and `tlp` are both pretty good.

To install Laptop Mode Tools, run `sudo apt-get install laptop-mode-tools` From within Terminal.

To install TLP, run these commands in Terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linrunner/tlp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tlp tlp-rdw
sudo tlp start
```

Hopefully, these will lower your temperature some. They brought mine down 10-20 degrees C, so any difference should be pretty noticable.

Comment: yeah it lowered the temperature but when I play some vedio on firefox or open multiple tabs ,the tempearture again increase and it reaches around 80-85, I have edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

## You can use [nbfc](https://github.com/hirschmann/nbfc) to control the fan

I'm using an Acer Aspire E5-573G laptop and nothing else worked to control the CPU fan, but [nbfc](https://github.com/hirschmann/nbfc/wiki/First-steps). I'm using Ubuntu 18.04. The exact profile for my model is missing, but nbfc worked fine with another similar profile (Acer Aspire E5-575G). If you don't know which profile to use, you can try:
`mono nbfc.exe config -r`

You will need the latest mono version to build it on Ubuntu 18.04, so don't forget to read [How to build NBFC on ubuntu](https://github.com/hirschmann/nbfc/wiki/How-to-build-NBFC#ubuntu).

Also I edit the default profile to turn the fan policy more aggressive to low the temperature.