# AMD dual graphics

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, radeon

My laptop is Acer Aspire 4745G with dual graphics Intel/AMD. Discrete card is Mobility Radeon HD 5430/5450/5470. I'm using Ubuntu 13.10 now.

One day I mentioned that my discrete AMD graphics card is not working, after some googling I found a way how to check it and command `fglrxinfo` gave me X Error of Bad Request. And so started my big quest for trying to make it work.

I tried so many ways from Google but no one of them really helped - I still can't use discrete card. I wouldn't even want to be able to switch them - I just want a discrete one work.

The last one I tried is installing driver from official site. Ok, so I installed it with sudo `sh ./amd*.run`, it processed and gave me DKMS error in the end or smth like that. After that I rebooted and got a message that system couldn't detect drivers and so on.

**So my question is:**

- how do I install drivers for my graphics card now, in 2014?

Comment: Ok, the last one was this: I installed a fresh Ubuntu 12.04 from official website and installed the latest driver from AMD website. Installation seemed to finish up ok, but after reloading I got a message about low-graphics mode.

Comment: See [How do I get AMD/Intel Hybrid Graphics drivers to work?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/205112/how-do-i-get-amd-intel-hybrid-graphics-drivers-to-work/288355#288355)

Comment: I followed this guide and after reboot I got "The system in running in low-graphics mode" message.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this tutorial: https://xpressrazor.wordpress.com/2013/10/08/enable-and-use-open-source-radeon-drivers-in-a-muxless-hybrid-graphics-intelamd-setup/

I have an AMD/Intel Hybrid graphic system, anda thar was my choice. I don't want to use the privative driver (so many bugs... and, it's PRIVATIVE, I mean).

Now, my system works nice, with a pretty good performance in games, and without any fan problem.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Sorry for not responding so long. I found a lot of solutions on the Internet, but none of them helped. Finally I happened to change the laptop, so I forgot about this question. Unfortunately, I didn't check the suggested tutorial, so I would appreciate if someone tries it and tells us whether it helped.