# Installing and Only Using Radeon HD 6630M on VAIO VPC-CB15F

Tags: radeon, vaio, sony

At the moment my Sony VAIO VPC-CB15F is using only my integrated Intel HD Graphics 3000 graphics card with the "X.org X server - AMD/ATI display driver wrapper from xserver-xorg-video-ati" drivers, however I would like to:
a) Get my AMD Radeon HD 6630M graphics card working and;
b) Use the Radeon HD 6630M exclusively (i.e. not use the integrated Intel HD Graphics 3000 graphics card at all).

I'm not worried about whether it's propriety or Open Source drivers, just as long as I am either using my Radeon HD 6630M exclusively or I am able to switch between the two effortlessly (though as I said, I'd prefer the former)...

I previously asked this question back when I was using Ubuntu 13.10 ("Saucy Salamander"), however I've spent most of the year away from a computer with work and in the process, I even forgot that I had asked it!

Anyway, I'm now running Ubuntu 14.10 ("Utopic Unicorn"), and the instructions below do not work under this version of Ubuntu - even before I deviated (see below), I get errors and when I get to the (Ubuntu) version-specific commands, my attempts to use the same commands changed for Utopic Unicorn throw-up even more errors!

Any help in sorting things out would be greatly appreciated...

Comment: [How do I get AMD/Intel Hybrid Graphics drivers to work?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/205112/how-do-i-get-amd-intel-hybrid-graphics-drivers-to-work)

Answer (score 1):

I have the same system as yours with Ubuntu 14.04, and I hope it will work for you as well.

*this will also work for any AMD video cards, but if you have an x86 system, you might want to refer to the first resource link too.

First, download the prerequisite packages for x64:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential cdbs fakeroot dh-make debhelper debconf libstdc++6
sudo apt-get install dkms libqtgui4 wget execstack libelfg0 dh-modaliases
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic xserver-xorg-core libgcc1
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs lib32gcc1 libc6-i386
```

You'll need to download the newest AMD Catalyst Driver (Google is your friend). Make sure to save it in the Downloads folder.

Unzip the package (you might have to change the file name depending on the file version):

```
unzip ~/Downloads/amd-catalyst-14-4-rev2-linux-x86-x86-64-may6.zip
```

Make it executable:

```
cd fglrx*
sudo chmod +x amd-driver-installer*.run
```

If you're using 14.04, create Ubuntu Trusty package by typing:

```
sudo sh ~/Downloads/amd-catalyst-14-4-rev2-linux-x86-x86-64-may6.run --buildpkg Ubuntu/trusty
```

Install the package:

```
sudo dpkg -i fglrx*.deb
```

Switch to AMD card:

```
sudo aticonfig --px-dgpu
```

Reboot, and configure Xserver (xorg.conf file) for the first time:

```
sudo aticonfig --initial -f
```

Now reboot again.

If you encounter a black screen, for example, press Ctrl+Alt+F3, log into your account and run this command:

```
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
sudo startx
```

Resource: my twisted version of these links:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1930450

http://www.yourownlinux.com/2014/04/how-to-install-amd-catalyst-14-4-graphics-driver-in-linux.html

:)