# Are there any wired (gaming) controllers that "just work" or natively support Linux/Ubuntu?

Tags: games, steam, input-devices, gamepad

Pretty much as the title suggests, are there any wired (gaming) controllers that "just work" or *natively* support Ubuntu "out-of-the-box"?

Having spent *plenty* of time fighting ([ongoing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/414395/installing-and-only-using-radeon-hd-6630m-on-vaio-vpc-cb15f)) [battles](https://askubuntu.com/questions/397660/smart-scope-weather-in-celsius) [with Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/418150/computer-hangs-on-boot-logo-when-using-power-button), it'd be nice to have something that is *natively* supported or "just works" for a change...

It has to be *wired* - I have the Logitech F710, but it chews through batteries like they're going out of fashion and like many users, I am *constantly* having connectivity issues with it (under Microsoft Windows *and* Ubuntu)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question is here:
[How do I use the DUALSHOCK 4 with Ubuntu 14.10?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/546811/how-do-i-use-the-dualshock-4-with-ubuntu-14-10)

The Sony DUALSHOCK 4 works *natively* (out-of-the-box) over bluetooth with Ubuntu 14.10 ("Utopic Unicorn") or newer...

Full step-by-step instructions, comments and details are provided at the link above.