# How do I use the DUALSHOCK 4 with Ubuntu 14.10?

Tags: bluetooth, gamepad

Quite simply, how do I setup, configure and use the Sony DUALSHOCK 4 controller with Ubuntu 14.10 ("Utopic Unicorn")?

I remember the Linux kernel was updated a while back to add native support... Does this mean I should be able to simply pair it by bluetooth (from the notification area) and off I go?

Or is there more to it than this?

I tried to follow these instructions:
https://askubuntu.com/a/450091/230107

But when I type *sudo pip install ds4drv*, I am told *sudo: pip: command not found*.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Okay, all one needs to do is "pair" the controller just like any other bluetooth device - these instructions relate to the "regular" variant of Ubuntu, so adjust them accordingly if you use a different variant of Ubuntu or a different Linux-based operating system...

- Hold the [image: PlayStation logo] and `Share` buttons to put the controller into "pairing" mode (the Light Bar/LED *should* start to rapidly blink/flash), then pair the controller with the computer using the bluetooth settings (Settings → Bluetooth → Wireless Controller).

Once the controller is "paired", you can turn it on by pressing (not *holding*!) the [image: PlayStation logo] button - do this *before* starting Steam or a game, because sometimes they may not recognize the controller if you do this *after* opening Steam or a game.

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS ("Focal Fossa") and newer has pseudo-official support for the DUALSHOCK 4 (it correctly recognizes the DUALSHOCK 4 as a *gaming* controller) and Valve Software's Steam has *native/official* support... Ubuntu doesn't offer anything in the way of *configuration* for controllers at the time of writing, but Steam has a default setup available or you can configure the controller to your individual liking - to do this, go into "Big Picture Mode" and adjust the "Controller" settings.

A few points about what I have noticed however...

- Steam has *surprisingly* good support for the DUALSHOCK 4, and even many *older* games seem to work well enough... Numerous games available *outside of Steam* also seem to work well (such as those from GOG.com) - but it varies from game-to-game, so you'll need to experiment yourself.
- If you're using "Big Picture Mode" and you have connected your
  controller in Steam, it will show a "controller" icon for games
  which support the DUALSHOCK 4 (refer to "Tomb Raider" in the picture below).
  [image: Controller icon in Steam "Big Picture" mode]
- Steam will "work its magic" to get the DUALSHOCK 4 working *as
  expected* in *most* games (e.g. [image: PlayStation X] for
  "select"/"accept"/"enter" and [image: PlayStation O] for
  "cancel"/"decline"/"back"), however some games will still show
  Microsoft Xbox series icons, which may lead to some minor confusion.
- Some games (including numerous older games) support force-feedback
  (vibration), though this varies and you may need to enable this
  functionality within the game itself.
- Support for the "fancy" functionality of the DUALSHOCK 4 - such as
  accelerometer control and the touchpad - may not work in part or at
  all... I found a couple of games in Steam that supported the
  accelerometer (older games, too!), but support seems to be pretty
  mixed from game-to-game.
- You can check the battery status in Ubuntu's settings (under "Power"); if you look in the "Devices" section, you *should* see "Wireless Controller" with the current battery status listed.
  [image: Controller Battery]
- You will need to *manually* turn the controller off when you're
  finished with it, by holding the [image: PlayStation logo] button until it
  switches off (you *should* see the Light Bar/LED turn off).

Updated content of answer to reflect experience using Ubuntu LTS 18.04 ("Bionic Beaver") and the most recent version of Steam as at September 8th, 2018.

Comment: Is there anything else that needs to be done? I paired the PS4 controller just like you said but when I press the home button the controller will not stay on.

Comment: That's all I did and it worked fine - are you using Ubuntu 14.10 or higher? Native support for the DUALSHOCK 4 was introduced with version 3.15 of the Linux kernel, which first made its debut in Ubuntu 14.10...

Comment: This worked for me in Ubuntu 14.10, but my experience in 15.04 is Reya's: It pairs properly, but won't stay connected for more than 5 seconds. It works properly when wired, with Steam in Ubuntu, and works with a simple Bluetooth connection, or wired in Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 1):

Before typing, `sudo pip install ds4drv`, you need to type, `sudo apt install python3-pip` (or what version of python you have) `…-pip`.

Without pip installed, Ubuntu doesn't know what pip is.

Comment: Under no circumstance should you type in ALL CAPS in the terminal. Also, how does this answer the question, I'm puzzled..