# Ubuntu 14.04 Dual Shock 4 Controller Setup?

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth, gamepad

How do I get the touchpad of Sony's Dual Shock 4 Controller working?

Also how can I get this thing to work in Source Engine games? The buttons work but the Joysticks do not!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use the DUALSHOCK 4 with Ubuntu 14.10?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/546811/how-do-i-use-the-dualshock-4-with-ubuntu-14-10)