# Log Out problem after upgrading from 13.04 to 13.10

Tags: 13.10, lightdm, logout

After I've upgraded from Ubuntu **13.04 to 13.10**, I can no longer use the Session Indicator "**Log Out...**" menu.

As soon as I click on it, the screen goes blank with **no mouse or keyboard input**, so I cannot do anything other then pressing and holding the power button down to force the computer to shut down.

The same also happens if I enter the **Terminal** command `sudo service lightdm restart`.

I can switch to **Guest Session** but then I have the same problem again when I switch back to my user session, the only difference: the screen is not black but simply my regular **desktop screen is frozen**.

Any ideas that can help me out will be much appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks to the tip implied in [Sandeep](https://askubuntu.com/users/248855/sandeep)'s answer ("*I don't know exactly how it got solved ... I think this is due to graphics problem, may be some driver is missing*") I've solved the problem myself, and would like to write it down in case it might be helpful for others experiencing a similar problem:

It seems the problem was in deed associated with a graphics driver issue.

I have an AMD/Intel Hybrid graphics card, but I didn't have such a problem before when I first started using it without installing any AMD graphics driver from either Ubuntu repositories or AMD website.

**After installing the AMD graphics driver as explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205112/how-do-i-get-amd-intel-hybrid-graphics-drivers-to-work) the problem has disappeared.**

Comment: In such a case it would be best to flag your question as a duplicate of the one that turned out to be the solution.

Comment: @DavidFoerster : Yes, in the sense that the answer is the same - as I've stated - although the question is quite different ;-)

Answer (score -1):

The same problem I was facing with 12.04 LTS version. Now, it is solved, but I don't know exactly how it got solved. When I used to click on "Log Out..." option, my screen used to go pink, and no log in screen came. I think this is due to graphics problem, may be some driver is missing. What I did, I clicked on "Switch User Account..." under my username at top right side of screen. I got no pink screen, but login screen. Then I logged in back and restarted my laptop. Then, I clicked on "Log Out..." option. This time I got the login screen and no pink screen. After that, it is running fine. Actually, there is login screen, but due to graphics problem, you are not able to see it. When you get that black screen, don't bother, just type in your account password, press "Enter", and you will be logged back in.....Hope, it may help you solve your problem....

Comment: There's no "Switch User Account..." in Ubuntu 13.10. Only "Guest Session" and then "<Current User>" and then "Log Out..." so I cannot follow your steps unfortunately. I'll look closer to the possibility of and underlying graphics problem though, thanks...