# Ubuntu 14.04 EliteBook 8460p constant fan, hot, short battery

Tags: 14.04, power-management, battery, overheating, fan

Finally took the plunge from Ubuntu in VM to wiping Windows and installing Ubuntu 14.04. I'm liking it so far although I've noticed the laptop gets hot very quickly, the fan is constantly on, and the battery lasts about 30 min. With Windows it stayed cool, quiet, and could last almost 3.5 hours.

I've switched to a non-Unity, 2D desktop, using TLP, and turned down brightness to no added benefit. I'm thinking this may be with the Graphics card? If so, here's  `lspci | grep VGA`

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Seymour 
[Radeon HD 6400M/7400M Series]
```

That's just my guess, any suggestions/recommendations? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

installing amd driver http://support.amd.com/pt-br/download/desktop?os=Linux+x86 fixed for me.
something very similar to:
[How do I get AMD/Intel Hybrid Graphics drivers to work?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/205112/how-do-i-get-amd-intel-hybrid-graphics-drivers-to-work)

hope it helps

t.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I was looking for, thanks!