# limit total CPU usage using tlp

Tags: cpu, tlp

how can force system to use only 50% of CPU power using TLP?
i mean which items should be changed in tlp config file (etc/default/tlp)?

Comment: Why would you want to reduce CPU power to 50%? What is the problem that you're trying to solve? Overheating? Cheers, Al

Comment: yes.fan working problem.

Comment: How old is the computer? Desktop or laptop? Do you have a dual-boot configuration? If so, do the fans work under Windows? Best we try and solve the fan problem instead of trying to reduce CPU. Cheers, Al

Comment: hp 8460p. no dual boot.but in windows every things is ok.in linux for every job that cause increasing cpu usage such as previewing images file in nautilus fan goes to high.i had disabled fan always working in ac mode at bios.also in battery mode in linux there is no problem.

Comment: I'll have to place my lengthy reply in an answer, below...  Cheers, Al

Answer (score 2):

Thats quite simple provided your CPU uses the intel_pstate driver:

```
CPU_MAX_PERF_ON_BAT=50
```

Refer to [configuration](http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-configuration.html#scaling) for details.

Answer (score 1):

OK, here we go...

First... **DON'T TURN OFF YOUR FAN IN THE BIOS**. You'll burn up your machine.

I want you to check your BIOS. I went to **http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/swd/public/readIndex?sp4ts.oid=5056901&swLangOid=8&swEnvOid=2020** and found an older BIOS update. Please check this against your version. I'll show it below...

[image]

Next, I want you to upgrade your processor microcode, by installing **intel-microcode** using Synaptic. Install it, reboot the computer, and then in terminal type **dmesg|grep microcode** to see it in action.

Next, remove TLP and any other such tools installed, and instead, install **thermald**, again using Synaptic. In its default configuration, it should work on most machines out of the box. However there is a thermal-conf.xml file which can be customized for your hardware. I wrote a custom .xml file for my laptop. Read up (man) thermald and thermal-conf.xml to get more info. Thermald can be run in **--no-daemon** mode to see what it's doing, and to help write your own custom .xml file.

Next... with age, computers, especially laptops, get very dusty inside, and it clogs up fans and electronics. With the computer TURNED OFF, take a vacuum cleaner with an exhaust port, and blow dust out of the computer through the vents in the bottom case.

Do all these things and report back. Cheers, Al

edit: if all this fails, we'll check the following...

[My fan is always on but not in MSWindows (HP elitebook 8460p)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/298082/my-fan-is-always-on-but-not-in-mswindows-hp-elitebook-8460p)

[Ubuntu 14.04 EliteBook 8460p constant fan, hot, short battery](https://askubuntu.com/questions/564168/ubuntu-14-04-elitebook-8460p-constant-fan-hot-short-battery)

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1764858&p=10848757#post10848757 (this one has a minor error)

Comment: could you send me your thermald conf file?wich items should be changed?i dont want my cpu temp goes over 45 degree.

Comment: First do ALL of the things that I suggested first, and lets see if they solve the problem. Please report back EXACT details of your results. My conf file can't be dropped in instead of the default, but it can be used as an example. I can always send you my conf later. Cheers, Al

Comment: ok. bios is up to date.this is my thermald conf file.                                                                            http://wikisend.com/download/676852/thermal-conf.xml

Comment: Did you have to update the BIOS, or was it already up to date? Did you do the other items yet? Your thermal-conf.xmf is a good start. Did you use the --no-daemon mode to get you some of the values/etc? You need to remove the last 75% of example code, and I think that you need to change the line `<influence> 100 </influence>` because I don't think you want two devices with the same value. Please report back IN DETAIL about the other items, so that I know what eventually helped, or not. Cheers, Al

Comment: To see if thermald is working, in terminal, type `sudo tail -f /var/log/syslog` and start some app running that would normal kick in the fans. Cheers, Al

Comment: You forgot the ThermalSensor <Path>/some_path</Path>. Mine is set to <Path>/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/</Path>, but you'll have to figure out yours for yourself. Basically this location holds the current temperature. Cheers, Al

Comment: Please remember to vote/accept my answer if it was helpful. Cheers, Al

Comment: What's the final result? Did the problem get solved? Cheers, Al

Comment: no...nothing happend!

Comment: i updated bios.fan hardware is clean and no dust.i did every things that you noticed in here, i tested many distro such as pclinuxos,manjaro,opensuse,...in gtk based desktops like unity and gnome  fan and heating problem is more.but in kde its better a little.more smoother and faster and less heating. im confused! maybe its gpu heating.i want configure system to dont increase fan speed in every small jobs  like opening gnome software or muon discover! i dont know! maybe its better to back into windows...

Comment: No, not Windows! Giggle. See the 3 URLs that I posted in my original answer and see if they help. Cheers, Al

Comment: Oh, I forgot, in URL #3... do this instead... edit `/etc/default/grub` and edit the line to read this... `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_osi=Linux"`. Then in terminal, type `sudo update-grub` and reboot the computer. See if that helps. Let me know. Cheers, Al