# Lenovo g510 laptop Ubuntu 14.04 LTS no AMD Radeon card detected

Tags: 14.04, ati, lenovo, radeon, fglrx

I've got a Lenovo G510 laptop and Ubuntu 14.04 LTS installed on it and when I run `lspci | grep VGA` it only shows the Intel integrated graphics card, but no information about the AMD Radeon card at all.

What should I do? I've already tried various tutorials on installing proprietary AMD drivers (fglrx etc.), but it didn't help. The result was 'low graphics mode', so I had to uninstall the fglrx packages.

This is the output of the **lspci** command:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller (rev 06)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 05)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 (rev 05)
0:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d5)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #2 (rev d5)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev d5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM86 Express LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
01:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Opal XT [Radeon R7 M265] (rev ff)
08:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA8172 Fast Ethernet (rev 10)
```

Now I can see the AMD Radeon Card. It is AMD Radeon R7 M265. lspci is showing the amd card because I changed back from UMA Graphics to Switch Graphics in BIOS. HOwever, I can't install the AMD drivers for this video card. After reboot, the OS goes into low graphics mode. What can I do?

Comment: Please edit your question and add output of `lspci` terminal command.

Comment: Try this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/205112/how-do-i-get-amd-intel-hybrid-graphics-drivers-to-work

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** If this is a laptop: is your AMD Radeon enabled in the BIOS?

Comment: @Pilot6, I edited the question. As you can see there is no ATI video card displayed. It's weird, since my laptop do have the AMD Radeon HD8750M graphics card.

Comment: @Fabby, thanks for you reply. Yes, it is a laptop Lenovo g510. How can I enable or disable the AMD card in BIOS? I have already tried to switch between Switch Graphics and UMA graphics. Is this what are you taliking about?

Comment: Different BIOSes have different names for it, but there should be a third option: Switch - UMA and AMD.  UMA is definitely not the one you want, as that is the Intel card only.

Comment: @Fabby, I don't have AMD option in BIOS, only UMA. Does it mean that I don't have AMD card or it's damaged or something like that?

Comment: It looks like you do not have it? How did you know you had that card?

Comment: Sorry guys, the adapter in my laptop is most likely AMD Radeon R5 M230, not AMD Radeon HD8570.

Comment: How do you know it? Same models can come with or without discrete graphics.

Comment: Please see the updated output from lspci command. The graphics card is AMD Radeon R7 M265.

Comment: You can try to install the latest driver by `sudo apt-get install fglrx-updates`.